# how to change array values when reading a file

Tags: c, arrays, string, gtk, int

i have to change the value of an array of ints defined as a global variable in the main function from what i read from a file, the reading process is k, the comparison of the char with the "x" strings is k, however the assignation of new values on the position i of the array is not working.

```
//global variable
int matrix[55];

static void main()
{

FILE *readFile;
    char *caracter;
    readFile = fopen(fileName,"r");
    int i;

if (readFile == NULL)
        {
            g_print ("\nError");
        }
        else
        {
          while (caracter != EOF) 
          {
          caracter = fgetc(archivo);
          if (caracter == '*')
           matrix[i] = 1;
          if (caracter == ' ')
           matrix[i] = 2;
          if (caracter == '+')
           matrix[i] = 3;
          if (caracter == 'S')
           matrix[i] = 4;
          if (caracter == 'S')
           matrix[i] = 5;
          if (caracter == 'R')
           matrix[i] = 6;
          else
           matrix[i] = 7;
      i++;
      g_print ("%d", mapaJuego[i]);
          }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `caracter` is a *pointer*. If you read the documentation to [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) you will see that it returns an `int`.

You also use `caracter` before it's initialized, meaning it can actually *be* `EOF` even though you haven't read to it yet.

The first thing you should do is of course to fix the type. The second should be to change the loop condition to this:

```
while ((caracter = fgetc(archivo)) != EOF)
```

It does the assignment *and* checking for error/end-of-file in one expression.

Comment: fixing it would be changing caracter to an int type, and changing the loop condition (done both) however my new question is how can i compare what the caracter keeps with a char such as "*" if it is an int, what is it keeping?

Comment: @DiegöRivera nSince both `int` and `character` are integer types, the compiler handles the conversion between them for you. So comparing and `int` variable to a character literal such as `'*'` (note the single quotes) will work without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has much more problems. Apart the ones pointed out by Joachim:

1. *caracter* must be `int`
2. *caracter* is used uninitialized;

you have also the following issues:

1. *i* is used uninitialized (this is a blocker);
2. your `main()` function is static;
3. you are comparing `'S'` twice;
4. your code is suboptimal (everything is compared also after a match): just use a `switch..case` or, even better, a `strchr()` call;
5. your `main()` function is `void` (not a big deal, but prevents you from returning a specific value to the OS).